# How to successfully "merge" two sets of plain-objects with getters?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below I have two sets of plain-objects, and within each there is a getter. I'd love to find a way to merge these two objects. However when I merge them I'd like them to still be getters. I do not want the values within side getters to be resolved.

```
const love = {
  get cats() {
    return 'meow';
  },
};

const hate = {
  get dogs() {
    return 'woof';
  },
};

console.log({...love, ...hate}); // { cats: 'meow', dogs: 'woof' }
console.log(Object.assign(love, hate)); // { cats: [Getter], dogs: 'woof' }
```

Comment: Don't use spread syntax or `Object.assign`, they will always call the getters.

Answer (score 2):

Use `defineProperties` to put the properties on the object, spreading into it values from `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`:

```js
const love = {
  get cats() {
    return 'meow';
  },
};

const hate = {
  get dogs() {
    return 'woof';
  },
};

const result = Object.defineProperties({}, {
  ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(love),
  ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(hate),
});
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(result, 'dogs'));
```

Comment: All that precious type info is gone 

Comment: @ThomasReggi `const result: typeof love & typeof hate = …` should solve that

Answer (score 0):

Made this little nugget from @CertainPerformances answer:

```
function mergeGetters<A, B>(a: A, b: B): A & B {
  const result = Object.defineProperties(
    {},
    {
      ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(a),
      ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(b),
    }
  );
  return result;
}
```